# Invalid currentpageindex value. it must be >= 0 and the < pagecount

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that was throwing the error message below:

> Invalid currentpageindex value. it must be >= 0 and the < pagecount

This issue happens if I go to the second page in my application and then try to filter the results by entering a search term.

After some research I thought I had fixed the issue by adding this line to my code

```
gridResult.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
```

So the code block now looks like this:

```
private void gridResult_PageIndexChanged(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    gridResult.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    FillGrid(tbSearch.Text);
    gridResult.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
}
```

This stops the original issue with the error I was encountering explained above. However now if I navigate to the second page in my paging and then click to go back to the first page the data is not refreshed it just holds on to the data in the second page.

I have been struggling to find any solution for this, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: presumably the grid only refreshes when NewPageIndex != CurrentPageIndex. You could try temporarily assigning CurrentPageIndex to 1 and then back to 0, but only if you have 2 pages (presumably when you have only a single page there isn't an issue)

Comment: @JamesBarrass Hi can you supply a code snippet not sure I quite follow.